# Possuk when washing for bread?

Tags: minhag, chasidut-hasidism, netilat-yadayim-washing, bread, nusach-sefard

There is a hassidish minhag to say a possuk--between washing the hands and before the brachach--when washing hands for bread. For the life of me I cannot remember which possuk it is, but I remember it being pretty universal across Hasidic sects. Can anyone tell me what possuk it is? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Many say the [following](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.134.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) passuk:

> שְׂאֽוּ־יְדֵכֶ֥ם קֹ֑דֶשׁ וּ֝בָרְכ֗וּ אֶת־ה'׃
>
> Lift your hands toward the sanctuary and bless *Hashem.*

Comment: [Sefaria's Siddur Sefard](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Siddur_Sefard%2C_Mealtime_Blessings.3?lang=bi&lang2=en) has this: "שְׂאוּ יְדֵיכֶם קוֹדֶשׁ וּבָרְכוּ אֶת ה': **וְאֶשָׂא כַפַּי אֶל מִצְוֹתֶיךָ אֲשֶׁר אָהַבְתִּי וְאָשִׂחָה בְחֻקֶּיךָ**".